# Export Excel file using xlsHelper

Tags: cakephp

I am using xlsHelper of cakephp to export in excel format.It is working fine in all the major browser and opening file in all operating system except "mac" operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this help you..

```
<?php 
    $this->layout="";
    $filename=strtotime("now");
    header ("Expires: 0");
    header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
    header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header ("Pragma: no-cache");
    header ("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".xls");
    header ("Content-Description: Generated Report" );

   // echo 'Number of Rows::'."\t" . count($test)."\n";
   // echo "\n";
    echo    'Id' . "\t" . 
            'EnrollmentId' . "\t" . 
            'IDS' . "\t" . 
            'sysreq' . "\t" . 
            'sysproc' . "\t" . 
            'Request' . "\t" .
            'Response' . "\t" .
            'Created' . "\n";
    foreach($test as $val): 
           echo $val['abc']['id']. "\t" .
                $val['xyz']['enrollment_id']. "\t" .
                $val['bca']['IDS']. "\t" .
                $val['mca']['_sysreq']. "\t" .
                $val['car']['_sysproc']. "\t" .
                $val['azx']['SYSBATCHNO']. "\t" .
                $val['tyu']['MSGS']. "\t" .
                $val['wer']['created']. "\n";
    endforeach;
```

?>